# Wordpress blog infected with META refresh tag

Tags: wordpress, meta

When I'm logged in I'm seeing this malicious META refresh code. I've not added. I believe my site was hacked recently.

However, when I'm not logged in, there is no such code. How do I find and fix it?

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://adf ly/xxxx/">
```

I'm thinking someone is making money out of my site by adding the code. It's not visible for public for some reasons. It just appears when I'm logged in.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be one of those free-to-use plugins?

Answer (score 0):

first update your WordPress.
then you will see in the WordPress management in "pages" a page with this "metadata" name.
just remove that page.